# Posting data to database through a "workflow" (Ex: on field changed to 20, create new record)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm looking to post new records on a user triggered basis (i.e. workflow). I've spent the last couple of days reasearching the best way to approach this and so far I've come up with the following ideas:

**(1)** Utilize Django signals to check for conditions on a field change, and then post data originating from my Django app.

**(2)** Utilize JS/AJAX on the front-end to post data to the app based upon a user changing certain fields.

**(3)** Utilize a prebuilt workflow app like http://viewflow.io/, again based upon changes triggers by users.

Of the three above options, is there a best practice? Are there any other options I'm not considering for how to take this workflow based approach to post new records?

Comment: The second approach of monitoring the changes in the front end and then calling a backend view to update go database would be a better approach because processing on the backend or any other site would put the processing on the server which would slow down the site whereas second approach is more of a client side solution thereby keeping server relieved

Comment: Thanks Amartya! That does make sense, the only concern I had taking the front-end approach was to the extent there is a risk of possible unexpected consequences, such as a "workflow" not completing. For example, if a user loss internet connection between changing a field, and the browser posting the data. Taking a backed approach I assumed I wouldn't have to overcome that same risk

Comment: I do not think there will be a data loss,  you are just trying to monitor a change,  as soon as it changes your view will update the database,  you can also use cookies or sessions to keep appending values as a list and update the database when site closes. Also django gives https errors you could put proper try and except conditions in that case as well.  Anyways cookies would be a good approach I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that finds this post I ended up deciding to take the Signals route. Essentially I'm utilizing Signals to track when users change a fields, and based on the field that changes I'm performing certain actions on the database.

For testing purposes this has been working well. When I reach production with this project I'll try to update this post with any challenges I run into.

Example:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=subTaskChecklist)
def do_something_if_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk) #define obj as "old" before change values
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        pass 
    else:
        previous_Value = obj.FieldToTrack
        new_Value = instance.FieldToTrack #instance represents the "new" after change object
        DoSomethingWithChangedField(new_Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second approach of monitoring the changes in the front end and then calling a backend view to update go database would be a better approach because processing on the backend or any other site would put the processing on the server which would slow down the site whereas second approach is more of a client side solution thereby keeping server relieved.

I do not think there will be a data loss, you are just trying to monitor a change, as soon as it changes your view will update the database, you can also use cookies or sessions to keep appending values as a list and update the database when site closes. Also django gives https errors you could put proper try and except conditions in that case as well. Anyways cookies would be a good approach I think